# PHP Zend YoutTube API Upload - A developer key is required for this operation error

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, upload, youtube

I am trying to do a browser based upload to YouTube. I am using PHP, Zend Framework 2 and ZendGData Client Library for ZF2. I have set it up following the Google Developers guide and have successfully been able to perfomr unauthorised requests - i.e. search videos. I have also been able to do an authorised request - i.e. Retrieve my full name from my YouTube account.

When I try to do uploads - retrieve an upload token I get the error:

**Expected response code 200, got 403**

**A developer key is required for this operation**

**Error 403**

My uploader controller is shown below. I have set up a developer key using https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard as outlined in the tutorial and included it in my code. Also the corresponding user/email and password are provided. I am using Curl to connect to the API which is not covered in the dev guide but I do not think that is the problem.

`

```
namespace Uploader\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use ZendGData\YouTube;
use ZendGData\ClientLogin;
use Zend\Http\Client\Adapter;


class UploaderController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {   
        $adapter = new Adapter\Curl();
        $curl = new \ZendGData\HttpClient();
        $curl->setAdapter($adapter);

        $adapter->setOptions(array(
            'curloptions' => array(
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
            )
        ));

        $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
        $httpClient = ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                          $username = '***********@gmail.com',
                          $password = '*********',
                          $service = 'youtube',
                          $client = $curl,
                          $source = 'Testing', // a short string identifying your application
                          $loginToken = null,
                          $loginCaptcha = null,
                          $authenticationURL
                          );

        $developerKey = 'AI39si55e**********************************************************************nY9p5NJ8y-8PwS9d8Jw';
        $applicationId = 'Testing';
        $clientId = "Youtube Tester V1";

        $yt = new YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
        $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);

        $myVideoEntry = new YouTube\VideoEntry;

        $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
        // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');

        // Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
        // and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
        $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');

        $tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
        $tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);

        $data = array('tokenValue' => $tokenArray['token'], 'postUrl' => $tokenArray['url']);

        return new ViewModel( $data );
    }

}
```

`

So as far as I can tell I have pretty much exactly followed the developer guide and have a developer key but still getting an error. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2):

```
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $clientId, $developerKey);

// vendor/zendframework/zendgdata/library/ZendGData/YouTube.php
public function getFormUploadToken(
        $videoEntry, $clientId, $developerKey,
        $url='https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken')
    {
        //$extraHeaders = $this->getHttpClient()->getRequest()->getHeaders()->toArray();
        $extraHeaders = array(
            'X-GData-Client' => $clientId,
            'X-GData-Key' => 'key='. $developerKey
        );

        if ($url != null && is_string($url)) {
            // $response is a Zend\Http\Response object
            $response = $this->post($videoEntry, $url, null, null, $extraHeaders);
            return self::parseFormUploadTokenResponse($response->getBody());
        } else {
            throw new App\Exception(
                'Url must be provided as a string URL');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So after struggling with this myself for a while, I finally found a hacky workaround that works just fine. It would seem as if the dev key you provide when instantiating the YouTube object is not being inserted into the header. To fix this, just provide the header when you execute the operation. This works for any entry such as Playlists or Videos.

```php
$dev_key = '****';
$entry = new ZendGData\YouTube\VideoEntry();
// do entry stuff here
$uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads'
$className = 'ZendGData\YouTube\VideoEntry';
$extraHeaders = array('X-GData-Key' => "key=$dev_key");
try {
    $yt->insertEntry($entry, $uploadUrl, $className, $extraHeaders);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```